# Deleting and inserting elements into an array of song titles

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm learning how to teach myself to delete and insert elements in an array. Here is the array I'm working with, which is just a bunch of song titles:

```
public class Algorithms
{

public static void main ()
{Song[] topTenSongs = {new Song("The Twist"), 
        new Song ("Smooth"),
        new Song ("Mack the Knife"),
        new Song ("How Do I Live"),
        new Song ("Party Rock Anthem"),
        new Song ("I Gotta Feeling"),
        new Song ("Macarena (Bayside Boys Mix)"),
        new Song ("Physical"),
        new Song ("You Light Up My Life"),
        new Song ("Hey Jude")
    };

    String[] tenSongNames = {"The Twist",
        "Smooth",
        "Mack the Knife",
        "How Do I Live",
        "Party Rock Anthem",
        "I Gotta Feeling",
        "Macarena (Bayside Boys Mix)",
        "Physical",
        "You Light Up My Life",
        "Hey Jude"};


    for (int i = 0; i < topTenSongs.length; i++)
    {topTenSongs [i].setTitle(tenSongNames[i]);
        System.out.println(topTenSongs [i].getTitle());


}
```

My goal is to create a for loop to iterate over the length of the songs array. I'm deleting the song title "I Gotta Feeling" from the middle of the array. I want to copy the next song in the array to the current location, and continue iterating, replacing the next song into the current location until I've reached the end of the array. Then, I want to write a new for loop to display the contents of my new, shorter song list (the last spot in the last index, 9, for the array should now say "null").

This is what I have so far. I'm confused with the whole iteration process where I can move the songs list up to an earlier index.

```
int chosenIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <topTenSongs.length; i ++) {
if (topTenSongs[i].getTitle().equals("I Gotta Feeling")==true){
chosenIndex = i;}} 

for (int i = chosenIndex; i < topTenSongs.length -1; i++) {
topTenSongs[i] = topTenSongs[i+1];
if(topTenSongs[i+1].getTitle().equals("Macarena (Bayside Boys Remix")==true){
    chosenIndex = i+1;
    String iteration = topTenSongs[i+1].getTitle();}
}

for (int i = 0; i< topTenSongs.length; i++) {
System.out.println(topTenSongs);
}
```

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Hello! I'm able to keep the arrays at the same size by simply moving up each song to replace the one that was taken out. The one that was taken out will now be represented for by a "null" slot in the final spot of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to specifically use arrays so that you can get practice with for loops and what not. Otherwise, as @CarlosHeuberger pointed out using an `ArrayList` will be much easier.

Let's go through what you have at the moment.

```
int chosenIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <topTenSongs.length; i ++) {
if (topTenSongs[i].getTitle().equals("I Gotta Feeling")==true){
chosenIndex = i;}}
```

First of all, please try to use conventional java code styling so that your code is as easy as possible to follow. Indentation and bracket placement goes a long way toward readability, like this:

```
int chosenIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <topTenSongs.length; i ++) {
    log.debug(topTenSongs[i].getTitle());
    if (topTenSongs[i].getTitle().equals("I Gotta Feeling")) {
        chosenIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Note that I removed the `==true` portion of your if-statement since that is redundant. Otherwise, this correctly finds the index you wish to remove so nice job there.

Let's look at the next part (again with corrected formatting):

```
for (int i = chosenIndex; i < topTenSongs.length -1; i++) {
    topTenSongs[i] = topTenSongs[i+1];
    if(topTenSongs[i+1].getTitle().equals("Macarena (Bayside Boys Remix")){
        chosenIndex = i+1;
        String iteration = topTenSongs[i+1].getTitle();
    }
}
```

To be honest I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. It *looks* like you want to shift all remaining songs to the left to fill in the gap, which is what you do at the beginning, but I have no idea what purpose the second part of the loop is. You are skipping the index if it matches a particular song, but what if you use a different array, where there is no song that matches "Macarena"? Try to avoid brittle coding like this, and make a solution that works with any data.

You had the right idea, but you need to think it through a bit more. Let's think through how to do this. When we have chosen an index to remove, we want to then:

1. Iterate over the list, starting with the `chosenIndex`,
2. Replace the element at each index with the index of the next song...
3. EXCEPT when we reach the end of the list, in which case we need to set that element to null

Now, let's put it all together:

```
for (int i = chosenIndex; i < topTenSongs.length; i++) {
    if(i == topTenSongs.length-1) {
        topTenSongs[i] = null; //set last element to null
    } else {
        topTenSongs[i] = topTenSongs[i+1];
    }
}
```

Now we have an array with your desired song removed, and the last element as a `null` to represent the empty slot. Do note that you will now need to check that each element is not `null` before calling `getTitle()` on them, or java will throw a `NullPointerException`. So, your print loop will have to look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < topTenSongs.length; i++) {
    if(topTenSongs[i] != null) {
        System.out.println(topTenSongs[i].getTitle());
    } else {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```

As an additional task to you, try to take this code and create a method you can call on any array of songs to remove a song with a specific title from it.